# swiftでTableViewの画面遷移先も同じようなTableViewを表示させる方法は？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

swiftで、下の写真のようなデータの編集（追加）ができるTableViewの、画面遷移先でもデータの編集や追加もできるTableViewにするにはどうすればいいですか？
イメージとしてはフォルダーの中にファイルがある感じです。
データベースみたいのも使いますか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

質問に書かれてる情報だけでは前提としている条件がよくわからないため、StoryboardとUINavigationControllerを使用している状況で、同じ画面に遷移する方法を説明します。

やることは簡単で、実際に遷移するタイミングで同じViewControllerを生成してpushするだけです。

```
func moveToNext() {
    let id = "Folder"
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(id) as! UIViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

idには、Storyboardで指定したStoryboard IDが入ります。

あとは、それぞれの画面がデータのどこに対応するのかを管理するようにすれば、どの画面でもデータの編集ができるようになるかと思います。